# Best way to code numerical user entry with JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, calculator, currency

I am developing a Java Swing application that has a number pad using JButtons. It has numbers 0 - 9, a dot for the decimal and an enter button. Obviously, the number on the button is just a character and not an integer as I intend it to be.

I want the user to be able to click the buttons to enter a currency amount such as $25.68. When they have finished they will press enter.

I want to take this amount and put it into a double variable.

In the actionPerformed function I will do the usual:

```
if (e.getSource() == numberButton1){
    //put in first index of array
}
```

Initially I thought I would put this into an array of integers and account for the dot button by assigning it to -1 and the enter as -2. But once I have the numbers in the array they will be backwards and I know I could read them out in reverse by counting the number of elements and starting at the last index then using a factor of 10 as I go along but all this seems overly complicated. Not to mention having to account for the decimal place. So before I start writing a million lines of code I thought I would ask...

...is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a global String value. For each numeric or dot(.) button press concatenate the number or dot to the string. Then parse the string as double when you need to use it. Here is an example:

```
String value = "";
// Lines of code
if (e.getSource() == numberButton1)
{
    value += "1";
}
if (e.getSource() == dotButton)
{
    value += ".";
}
// Do the same for other numbers
// When you need the value as a double do the following
double _value = Double.parseDouble(value);
```

PS: Don't forget to add a check if user presses the dot two times. You cannot have two decimals.

Answer (score 2):

Consider taking a look at [Actions API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), it will allow you to define a self contained action which you can configure any way you like

For example...

```
public class NumberAction extends AbstractAction {

    private char value;
    private JTextField field;

    public NumberAction(char value, JTextField field) {
        this.value = value;
        this.field = field;
        putValue(NAME, Character.toString(value));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = field.getText();
        text += value;
        field.setText(text);
    }

}
```

Now, I've simply used `char` as the base value as, realistically, your not actually making use of the any kind of numeric value...

You would construct your buttons doing something like...

```
JButton num7 = new JButton(new NumberAction('7', field);
JButton num8 = new JButton(new NumberAction('8', field);
JButton num9 = new JButton(new NumberAction('9', field);
//...
```

For example...

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate all inputs in string
Then at enter button clicked parse the string as double

Declar

```
String value ="";
double val =0;
```

At each button

```
value=value+"3";
```

And...

```
value=value+".";
```

And so on.

Then at enter button

```
val =Double.parseDouble(value);
```

Now its numiric double... Use it